# JavaScript double click event?

Tags: javascript

**Scripts**

```
var timer;
var firing = false;
var begen = function(id) {
    alert('one click');
};

var popupAc = function(id) {
    alert('double click');
};

function cc(id) {
    if (firing) {
        popupAc(id);
        clearTimeout(timer);
        firing = false;
        return;
    }
    firing = true;
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        begen(id);
        clearTimeout(timer);
        firing = false;
    }, 250);
}​
```

**Html**

```
<div id="myID" onclick="cc()">Click Here</div>​
```

**Example**: http://jsfiddle.net/LXSZj/11/

**Question:**

It works fine with ie and chrome, But in firefox, when I double click, I get two alert functions.(alert double click event and one click event)

How can I fix It?

Thanks.

Comment: Just an FYI: You do not have to set a boolean for the timer, you can use the timer object itself. So instead of `if(firing)` you can do `if(timer)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move your clearTimeout above the alert

```
clearTimeout(timer);
popupAc(id);
```

PS: I might be wrong, just guessing, not having firefox here..

Comment: Thanks, Could you explain, why this happened? I cant understand.

Comment: I would say that the second alert gets queued up, because the clearTimeout is executed too late (if you are not quick enough to close the first alert before).

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
  var timer;
  var x = false;

  function myfun(){
    if(timer){
    clearTimeout(timer);
    alert('double click');   
    timer = 0;
     return;
    }
  timer = setTimeout(function(){
                    alert('singleclick');
                    timer=0;
                    clearTimeout(timer);                   

                },250)

            }
        </script>
        </head>
        <body>

         <p>If you singleclick/double-click on me, I will alert.</p>
            <p> i will also alert based on your click</p.

         <script>
       (function(){
     pelem = document.getElementsByTagName('p');

       for(var i=0;i<pelem.length;i++){
      pelem[i].addEventListener('click',myfun,false);
     }

   })()
  </script>

    </body>
      </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To **control double click problems**, i built this function, basically for every function **you want to protect against the user clicking too fast**, double click etc.. you call this function instead and define the timing range of release of the function. This is usefull to avoid API or endpoint calls that makes no sense or would be repetitive, or abusive in some cases.

*The **method_name** parameter is just any label you desire, just in case you want to check the prevented array lists with console.log(runnning_methods);*

**Usage example:**

```js
                  
    var runnning_methods={};
    function preventQuickMethod(method_name,callback,delay_time){
      if(!delay_time){var delay_time=500;}
      if(runnning_methods[method_name]==1){return;}
      setTimeout(function(){ runnning_methods[method_name]=0; console.info(method_name+" released");},delay_time);
      runnning_methods[method_name]=1;
      callback();
    }
      
      
      function nextpage(){
        preventQuickMethod("dismissSlot",function(){
            document.getElementById("btn").innerHTML="fired at "+Date.now();
        },1000);
    }
```

```html
<button onclick="nextpage()">Fire!</button>
<span id="btn" >EHHEHE</span>
```